# How to deal with identity in a new country established using short name?

Tags: canada, british-columbia, identity-document

What would be the simplest or cheapest way to fix/avoid an issue caused by an immigrant who established their identity documents using their short name (eg. Tim) instead of the name on their birth certificate?

Potential issues could for example be, how to deposit a large cheque (eg. house sale) to a bank account made in the short name.

Is it legal to use new ID from the country of origin to open a bank account in the full name?

Can a notary or lawyer create some kind of attestation document that 'marries' the short name ID and the long name ID to the actual person?

Comment: No doubt you have various documents, such as a driver's license, from a Canadian province. Changing your name with the province may be a separate matter from changing it with the national government. So what in what province do you reside?

Comment: @GerardAshton British Columbia

Comment: We can and will not give legal advice to your specific situation on the Stack as that is banned by the stack rules and might be deemed an unlicensed practice of law in your area. You might want to look for legal advice from a practitioner in your area. First consultations can usually be gained at a fixed rate or free.

Comment: @Trish but this question can be answered generally without giving specific legal advice.

Comment: @phoog as asked, it is not general but a Request for specified legal advice, which is against policy

Comment: @Trish shall I rewrite it in more general terms, such as; is it possible to deposit a cheque made out to an alias - or, what is the role of an alias in law and how does it relate to short names?

Comment: @Trish I have rewritten it, hopefully it is acceptable in this more general form, thanks.